# csh: How to check if symbolic link exists?

Tags: symbolic-link, csh

Symbolic link was create by command `ln -s`.
Tried `if ( -e "$link" )` and `if ( -f "$link" )`. But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working in a tcsh (often installed as csh on Linux), then  `if ( -l "$link")` should work.

The `-l` operator checks if a file is a symbolic link. I don't think there is an build-in equivalent in the plain csh.